# .NET MAUI iOS sideloaded app using App Center & Firebase App Distribution installs but doesn't update

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, maui

It's a .NET MAUI 8.03 iOS app built using an Azure DevOps Pipeline. It Targets iOS 17 with Support for iOS 16.1. I added the Version # to the login page which is why I know it's not updating. The app installs with no problems, but the Version on the login page never changes. I'm also not getting the correct Version number in Sentry.io. I'm even passing the app Version # in a daily API call I'm making to the database. The Version # is not updating. I get the Verifying, Loading, and Installing messages with a clock spin showing the progress of the app install. There is no error message.

My test device used to work just fine. I was running iOS 16.7.2. I recently upgraded to iOS 17.3.1. I think that's when the problem started. I have another test device running iOS 17.2 that is experiencing the same problem.

Is it a Target Version issue?

I just tried doing an iOS 17.3.1 build, but I got an error stating that .NET MAUI only supports iOS 11 - iOS 17.2.

I'm using XCode 15.1 and the latest version of .NET MAUI.

Can I use a BETA version of .NET MAUI to build this? If so, does anyone have a good rollback file?

Any help is much appreciated! Thanks!

**UPDATE 1:**

I built an iOS 17.2 Version of the app and installed it on an iPhone 13 running iOS 17.2. The problem still persists. The app installs, but the Version does not update.

**UPDATE 2:**

I added a png file to the Images/Resources folder. I named it tracking_image_1_0_17 which is the same Version number as my app. I then built the app and downloaded the ipa file from App Center. The next step was to rename the file to a zip file using Power Shell, so I could unpack it. (ren MyAppName.ipa MyAppName.ipa.zip) I then unzipped the package and my tracking image was in there. So, the ipa file is correct.

**UPDATE 3:**

The issue started around the same time that Azure DevOps updated to .Net MAUI 8.0.6. From 2/13 - 2/26, Azure DevOps was using on old version of .Net MAUI that was causing build issues. That issue resolved around Feb 16th. I'm now trying to find or create a rollback file to use the .Net MAUI 8.0.3 build.

Answer (score 0):

The problem turned out to be the AppLinks code that I added on Feb 13th. This was the exact same time as builds also started to fail in my Azure Pipelines due to a .Net Maui issue (started defaulting to 8.0.0 code). Once the builds started to work a few days later because of .Net Maui 8.0.6, I figured the version issue I was having had something to do with .Net Maui. Anyway, if anyone else experiences this issue it was AppLinks. I followed these instructions. I have since commented out the AppLinks code and the app is now updating as expected.

https://github.com/Redth/MAUI.AppLinks.Sample/tree/main

This is the code that caused the problem.

```
<ItemGroup Condition="$([MSBuild]::GetTargetPlatformIdentifier('$(TargetFramework)')) == 'ios' Or $([MSBuild]::GetTargetPlatformIdentifier('$(TargetFramework)')) == 'maccatalyst'">

    <!-- For debugging, use '?mode=developer' for debug to bypass apple's CDN cache -->
    <CustomEntitlements
        Condition="$(Configuration) == 'Debug'"
        Include="com.apple.developer.associated-domains"
        Type="StringArray"
        Value="applinks:redth.dev?mode=developer" />

    <!-- Non debugging, use normal applinks:url value -->
    <CustomEntitlements
        Condition="$(Configuration) != 'Debug'"
        Include="com.apple.developer.associated-domains"
        Type="StringArray"
        Value="applinks:redth.dev" />

</ItemGroup>
```

Adding this line to Entitlements.plist causes the same problem.

```
<key>com.apple.developer.associated-domains</key>
<array>
   <string>applinks:mywebsite.azurewebsites.net/Leaderboard</string>
</array>
```

And finally, the real issue is that you have to add Associated Domains to the app Identifier in the Apple Developer Portal. Without this, the app will not update.